# Passing variable as a parameter for Set-MpPreference

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to configure Windows Defender via Set-MpPreference.

This is my code:

```
$ASRIds = "01443614-cd74-433a-b99e-2ecdc07bfc25,92E97FA1-2EDF-4476-BDD6-9DD0B4DDDC7B"
$ASRValues = "1,1"

Set-MpPreference -AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Ids $ASRIds -AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Actions $ASRValues
```

however, I am getting error

```
Set-MpPreference : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Actions'. Cannot
convert value "1,1" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.MpPreference.ASRRuleActionType[]".
Error: "Cannot convert value "1,1" to type
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.MpPreference.ASRRuleActionType". Error: "Unable to match the
identifier name 1,1 to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Disabled, Enabled, AuditMode""
At line:1 char:96
+ ... tionRules_Ids $ASRIds -AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Actions $ASRValues
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-MpPreference], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-MpPreference
```

I know that this can be done directly like this:

```
Set-MpPreference -AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Ids 1443614-cd74-433a-b99e-2ecdc07bfc25,92E97FA1-2EDF-4476-BDD6-9DD0B4DDDC7B -AttackSurfaceReductionRules_Actions 1,1
```

but passing it as variable is a necessary part of my project. Is there anything I can do to make the variables work?

One by one (working with only one attack surface reduction rule at the time) works, but Windows Defender disabled the other rules if you enable just one. So I need to have multiple IDs in the variable at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is not liking the fact that you're passing a string - try passing <s>an array</s> arrays:

```
$ASRIds = @("01443614-cd74-433a-b99e-2ecdc07bfc25","92E97FA1-2EDF-4476-BDD6-9DD0B4DDDC7B")
$ASRValues = @(1,1)
```

**Troubleshooting Notes**

- The `[]` in your error is telling us it is expecting an array

```
...Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.MpPreference.ASRRuleActionType[]...
```

- This part is telling us it's trying to match the whole string `1,1` to an enumerator - it should be matching one at a time.

```
Unable to match the identifier name 1,1 to a valid enumerator name
```

- I'm guessing you want to specify `Enabled`? Consider this, to make your code more readable: `$ASRValues = @('Enabled','Enabled')`

```
Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
Disabled, Enabled, AuditMode
```

- As for the error in the comments, [well...](https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/funny_error_messages/unknown-error-funny-error-messages.jpg)

Comment: Set-MpPreference : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code. Interesting error message, lol.